# Why my HDD drive space is showing 78% filled as i have formated my HDD 500GB and set it as /home

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage, home-directory, 22.04, user-space

today i have installed ubuntu 22.04 LTS, before that i was using 20.04LTS.

I have 2 drives
SSD of 128 GB and HDD of 500 GB. Before installing 22.04 my partition was
for SSD /root = 30GB, /boot = 1GB, /swap = 4GB and rest (128 - 30 - 1 - 4) for /home on my SSD. and i have used my 500 GB HDD for /usr/local only.
previously i used timeshift to backup my sys to that HDD drive.

Now, after installing 22.04 today, i have used my SSD as /swap = 12GB, /boot = 1GB, /efi = 1GB and /root = 114GB
and set my HDD as /home = 500GB

now i am seeing that only 107GB is free out of 500GB of my HDD.
where from these space get full?
[disk usage of SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIRdR.png),
[disk usage of HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQwgo.png)
if you have any solution to free up or format my HDD then help me as i have not used my /home to store any files.

Comment: Mount all your partitions and run these, post in question above to preserve formatting: `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,UUID,mountpoint` and `df -h` and `sudo fdisk -lu`

Comment: You mention /root; but you realize the root directory `/` is a different directory to `/root`   (ie. the directory `/root` is not the `/` (root) directory)

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

Using `gparted`, lay down a fresh MBR partition table on your HDD. **This will wipe the drive**. Then create a new 500G ext4 partition. Add the appropriate /home/username directory. Edit the /home line in /etc/fstab because the UUID has changed.

Because you **have bad blocks on this disk**, bad block the drive...

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this may take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```